# How to move a lot of small file on windows quickly windows 8 and 7

Tags: file, unzip, rar, unrar

I have done a computation during few weeks and have the result in 825 000 files of 40 octets.
I do not want use subfolder.
I have try to rar the folder (done in less than 20 minutes) and unrar on the second computer the file sent by skype but it will need few days to unrar it :s

Does someone have a solution to un rar unzip untar quickly a big number of very small files?

Thanks you!

Comment: You are targeting your energy at wrong place. Please take a tour to help you out with how/what to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in options: no compression, zip format, no date change.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common complaints about newer versions of Windows is the slow copying speed, especially when transferring lots of files over the network. If you want to speed up your copying or if you regularly transfer large amounts of data and have to stop the process to perform some other disk-intensive task. You can try TeraCopy.